# l (lowercase L) command in bash terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command

```
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/comp$ l
3rdParty/    que.ico     SE32.EXE   start.fgx  Supp/         WebResources/
autorun.inf  Readme.txt  START.EXE  start.fgz  Walkthrough/
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/comp$ ls
3rdParty     que.ico     SE32.EXE   start.fgx  Supp         WebResources
autorun.inf  Readme.txt  START.EXE  start.fgz  Walkthrough
vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/comp$
```

What is the difference between these two commands?

I tried `$ which l`, but there's no output.

Also no result for `$ man l`.

I also tried unsuccesfully to Google it.

Comment: Yeah, I can't imagine that Googling something like that would get you anywhere.

Comment: @asmeurer: [It does now](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+l+command&oq=bash+l+command)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`l` is probably an alias for something like `ls -F`.  The `-F` option causes `ls` to append `/` to directory names, `*` to executable regular files, etc.

**UPDATE :** Based on your comment, `l` is aliased to `ls -CF`. Single letter options can be "bundled", so `ls -CF` is equivalent to `ls -C -F`. The `-C` option causes `ls` to list entries by columns. This is the default if `ls` thinks it's writing to a terminal; the `-C` option makes it behave this way unconditionally. (`ls -1` lists one entry per line, which is the default if `ls` is *not writing to a terminal.)

`type -a l` should show you how it's defined.  It's probably set in your `$HOME/.bashrc`.

(The `$` is part of your shell prompt, not part of the command.)

Comment: `vikram@vikram-Studio-XPS-1645:~/comp$ type l

l is aliased to ls -CF'` ... Thanks, I got it man .. !!

Comment: Cool.  I knew about `which`, but not `type -a`.

Comment: A simpler way to check would be to simply run `alias` on the command you want to check. For example: `alias l` on my machine yields `alias l='ls -CF'`.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ `alias l` only tells you whether and how it's defined *as an alias*. There are several other ways it could be defined: as a command somewhere in `$PATH`, or as a shell function. `type -a l` will show you all of those definitions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no general command 'l' that exists or even does what 'ls' does that's why your results for `which l` and `man l` are empty

Do you have something on your path called `l` that perhaps runs `ls`?

Answer (score 0):

The way to find if its alias is to check ~/.bashrc file

```sh
$sudo cat ~/.bashrc | grep 'alias l='
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Comment: What if the alias is not set in .bashrc? A simpler way to check would be to simply run `alias` on the command you want to check. For example: `alias l` on my machine yields `alias l='ls -CF'`.

Answer (score -1):

it's specific bash command for "ls".

```
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~$ mkdir ltest
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~$ cd ltest
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ echo 321 > 321.txt
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ echo 123 > 123.txt
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ ls
123.txt  321.txt
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ l
123.txt  321.txt
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ whereis asdasdasd #This command doesn't exists
asdasdasd:
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ whereis l #Results of "whereis l" and "whereis asdasdasd" are same
l:
ilia@Latitude-E6410:~/ltest$ sh #Try "l" in sh
$ ls #"ls" is working
123.txt  321.txt
$ l #But "l" doesn't
sh: 2: l: not found
$
```

Comment: It's not a Bash command at all. The accepted answer says it all: it's an alias that is defined somewhere by a user created file or the distribution's maintainers. By the way, `which` and `whereis` are (in Bash) bad methods to determine what a command/function/alias is. Use `type -a` instead: `type -a l` will give you some information (but not where it is defined).

Comment: Yes, it's alias for ls -CF, sorry.